# AutoIT: ADODB.Connection method 'open' missing?

Tags: autoit, adodb

I want to use AutoIT to access a Maria DB via ADODB objects.
The creation of the ADODB.Connection object seems to work properly. But for some reason I cannot find, the open method fails. I am no AutoIT expert, but to me it does not look like the object had problems with the arguments.

The relevant lines of the code are:

```
$objConn = ObjCreate("ADODB.Connection")
ConsoleWrite("ADODB conn Error: " & @error & " - Typ: " & VarGetType($objConn) & @crlf)
$objConn.open ("DRIVER=" & $sDriver & ";SERVER=" & $sServer & ";DATABASE=" & $sDatabase & ";UID=" & $sUsername & ";PWD=" & $sPassword)
ConsoleWrite("conn Error: " & @error & @crlf)
```

The second ConsoleWrite is not reached. The Output and error-message are:

```
ADODB conn Error: 0 - Typ: Object
"C:\Users\mischneider\Documents\Automation_Base\udf\mysql.au3" (29) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.: 
$objConn.open ("DRIVER=" & $sDriver & ";SERVER=" & $sServer & ";DATABASE=" &
$sDatabase & ";UID=" & $sUsername & ";PWD=" & $sPassword) $objConn^ ERROR
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong and how I can open the connection?

Many thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: Could you please show your parameters like the connection string.

Comment: I didn't use a connection string, but the params in parenthesis (thought it was an alternative). They are as follows:

Comment: (couldn't save the changes) They are as follows:
$sDriver = {MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}  (installed and HKLM entry found in registry = 'installed')
$sServer = 'localhost'   (MySQL running and listening on 3306)
$sDatabase = 'test'   (DB Name in MySQL)
$sUsername = 'admin'
$sPassword = ''

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of and could resolve the problem.
My custom function took $sDriver with following (wrong) default value:

```
[...]$sDriver = "(MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver)", [...]
```

where parentheses () instead of braces {} were used. Correct is:

```
[...]$sDriver = "{MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}", [...]
```

The laptop screen is so small I didn't realize that. But inserting a working Connection string and then comparing it to the result of the concatenation char by char, I recognized the difference.

I hope this now documented accident will help others in my situation.

BR
Michael